# A container that sorts and determines uniqueness from two different fields

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, containers

Suppose I've defined a type such as

```
struct Item
{
    Item(int i, float j) : x(i), y(j) {}
    int x;
    float y;
};
```

I would like to keep these in a container that keeps them sorted by `Item::y`, and ensures that each entry has a unique `Item::x`. I need to be able to add items and remove the top item (i.e., the item with the smallest `y` value).

In other words, something that can do this:

```
Container<Item> my_container;
my_container.insert(Item(0, 3.2));
my_container.insert(Item(2, 1.1));
my_container.insert(Item(0, 0.2));
my_container.insert(Item(1, 0.6));
my_container.insert(Item(3, 0.6));
my_container.insert(Item(0, 6.1));

for (auto &i : my_container)
  std::cout << i.x << " " << i.y << std::endl;
```

This would ideally yield:

```
1 0.6
3 0.6
2 1.1
0 6.1
```

At first I was using `std::set<Item>` with a comparison function that ensured `item_1.y < item_2.y`, but this disallows an item to be added when `item_1.y == item_2.y` but `item_1.x != item_2.x`.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Update**

I decided to look into Boost Multi-Index seeing as I have Boost available. I nearly have a solution (using Joaquín's answer below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct Item
{
    Item(int i, float j) : x(i), y(j) {}
    int x;
    float y;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  Item,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<member<Item,float,&Item::y> >,
    ordered_unique<member<Item,int,&Item::x> >
  >
> my_container_t;

int main()
{
  my_container_t mc;
  mc.insert(Item(0, 3.2));
  mc.insert(Item(2, 1.1));
  mc.insert(Item(0, 0.2));
  mc.insert(Item(1, 0.6));
  mc.insert(Item(3, 0.6));
  mc.insert(Item(0, 6.1));

  const my_container_t::nth_index<0>::type& y_index = mc.get<0>();
  // Print
  for (auto &i : y_index)
    std::cout << i.x << " " << i.y << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This program's output is:

```
1 0.6
3 0.6
2 1.1
0 3.2
```

which is almost what I want. Note that inserting items with x = 0 did not replace the previous item in the container with that index. Also, as an aside, what is the best way to remove and return the top item in the container. Would something like this suffice:

```
Item pop(my_container_t &mc)
{
  my_container_t::nth_index<0>::type& container = mc.get<0>();
  auto item = *container.begin();
  container.erase(container.begin());
  return item;
}
```

Comment: Your sample has 6 inputs and 4 outputs, which is confusing.

Comment: @MooingDuck There are only 4 outputs because items with ``x=0`` were added three times. Much like a set, the last two of these items aren't added to the container because and item with ``x=0`` is already in the container.

Comment: Why didn't inserting `Item(0, 4.7)` overwrite `Item(0, 3.2)`?

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry that was a mistake, I've edited the question.

Comment: Assuming he is using his own custom container, can't he just change the logic of the insert function of the container such that it determines whether to add the item(based on the value of x) and what position to give it in the container(based on the value of y)?

Answer (score 4):

You want two containers: one ensures uniqueness of `x`, the other to provide ordering on `y` then `x`.

A `boost` `multi_index` container could do both at once, but may be overkill.

Have a `set` or `unordered_set` of `x` values in use, and discard things that are already there.

Have a `set` of elements ordered by `y` then `x` (`std::tie(y,x)<std::tie(o.y,o.x)` is the easiest&safest C++11 way), or a `multiset` ordered by `y`, to maintain order.  I prefer `set`s to `multiset`s myself, but that is probably just a character flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what others say, I don't consider using Boost.MultiIndex overkill: this is precisely the kind of situations the lib is designed for.

```
using namespace boost::multi_index;

typedef multi_index_container<
    Item,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<member<Item,float,&Item::y> >,
        ordered_unique<member<Item,int,&Item::x> >
    >
> my_container_t;
```